# Easiest way to filter <li> list using check box jquery

Tags: jquery, dictionary, checkbox, filtering

I am trying to get help in filtering this list using check boxes.

All li will be shown prior to the client selecting any filtering and return to that state if the client deselects all filters.

If multiple boxes are selected then each li that contains those categories will be shown.

Categories are shown within each li as a h6 span

```
<div class="tags">
<input id="artichoke" type="checkbox" name="artichoke" style="padding-left:40px;" value="artichoke">artichoke<br/>
<input id="arugula" type="checkbox" name="arugula" style="padding-left:40px;" value="arugula">arugula<br/>
<input id="asparagus" type="checkbox" name="asparagus" style="padding-left:40px;" value="asparagus">asparagus<br/>
<input id="beets" type="checkbox" name="beets" style="padding-left:40px;" value="beets">beets<br/>
<input id="broccoli" type="checkbox" name="broccoli" style="padding-left:40px;" value="broccoli">broccoli<br/>
<input id="brussels sprouts" type="checkbox" name="brussels sprouts" style="padding-left:40px;" value="brussels sprouts">brussels sprouts<br>
<input id="burdock" type="checkbox" name="burdock" style="padding-left:40px;" value="burdock">burdock<br/>
<input id="cabbage" type="checkbox" name="cabbage" style="padding-left:40px;" value="cabbage">cabbage<br/>
<input id="carrots" type="checkbox" name="carrots" style="padding-left:40px;" value="carrots">carrots<br/>
<input id="cauliflower" type="checkbox" name="cauliflower" style="padding-left:40px;" value="cauliflower">cauliflower<br/>
<input id="celery" type="checkbox" name="celery" style="padding-left:40px;" value="celery">celery<br/>
<input id="chinese greens" type="checkbox" name="chinese greens" style="padding-left:40px;" value="chinese greens">chinese greens<br>
<input id="collards" type="checkbox" name="collards" style="padding-left:40px;" value="collards">collards<br>
<input id="cucumbers" type="checkbox" name="cucumbers" style="padding-left:40px;" value="cucumbers">cucumbers<br/>
<input id="daikon" type="checkbox" name="daikon" style="padding-left:40px;" value="daikon">daikon          
</div>


<ul>
<li>
<h2>My Second Listing</h2>
<h3>My Second Listing Tagline</h3>
<h6 class="buying">Buying: <span class="Foods">Foods ,</span></h6>
<h6 class="selling">
        Selling: <span class="Foods                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
            Foods ,</span> <span class="asparagus                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                asparagus ,</span> <span class="beets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
                    beets ,</span> <span class="broccoli                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ">
                        broccoli ,</span> <span class="brussels sprouts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ">
                            brussels sprouts ,</span> <span class="burdock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                burdock ,</span> <span class="cabbage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                    cabbage ,</span> <span class="carrots                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                        carrots ,</span> <span class="cauliflower                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ">
                                            cauliflower ,</span> <span class="celery                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ">
                                                celery ,</span> <span class="chinese greens                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ">
                                                    chinese greens ,</span> <span class="collards                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ">
                                                        collards ,</span> <span class="cucumbers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                                                            cucumbers ,</span> <span class="daikon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ">
                                                                daikon ,</span> <span class="dry beans                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                                                                    dry beans ,</span>
    </h6>
    <a href="/ListingDetails.cshtml?id=18" class="btn-l link-processed purple">View Profile</a>
</li>
<li>
    <h2>
        My Third Listing</h2>
    <h3>
        My Third Listing Tagline</h3>
    <h6 class="buying">
        Buying: <span class="Foods                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
            Foods ,</span> <span class="artichoke                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                artichoke ,</span> <span class="arugula                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                    arugula ,</span> <span class="asparagus                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                        asparagus ,</span> <span class="beets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
                            beets ,</span> <span class="broccoli                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ">
                                broccoli ,</span> <span class="brussels sprouts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ">
                                    brussels sprouts ,</span> <span class="burdock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                        burdock ,</span> <span class="cabbage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                            cabbage ,</span> <span class="carrots                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                                carrots ,</span> <span class="cauliflower                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ">
                                                    cauliflower ,</span> <span class="celery                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ">
                                                        celery ,</span> <span class="chinese greens                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ">
                                                            chinese greens ,</span> <span class="collards                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ">
                                                                collards ,</span> <span class="cucumbers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                                                                    cucumbers ,</span> <span class="daikon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ">
                                                                        daikon ,</span>
        <span class="dry beans                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
            dry beans ,</span>
    </h6>
    <h6 class="selling">
        Selling: <span class="Foods                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
            Foods ,</span> <span class="arugula                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                arugula ,</span> <span class="asparagus                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                    asparagus ,</span> <span class="beets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ">
                        beets ,</span> <span class="broccoli                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ">
                            broccoli ,</span> <span class="brussels sprouts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ">
                                brussels sprouts ,</span> <span class="burdock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                    burdock ,</span> <span class="cabbage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                        cabbage ,</span> <span class="carrots                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ">
                                            carrots ,</span> <span class="cauliflower                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ">
                                                cauliflower ,</span> <span class="celery                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ">
                                                    celery ,</span> <span class="chinese greens                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ">
                                                        chinese greens ,</span> <span class="collards                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ">
                                                            collards ,</span> <span class="cucumbers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ">
                                                                cucumbers ,</span> <span class="daikon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ">
                                                                    daikon ,</span>
    </h6>
    <a href="/ListingDetails.cshtml?id=19" class="btn-l link-processed purple">View Profile</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand what you mean, cause you say you want them all to show, then when they click checkbox it will show the item....but if they're already starting out as shown, then they dont need to be shown.

So I reversed, and when they check, it takes it off the list?
But I dont think thats what you want?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/QC5gT/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(':checkbox').click(function(){
var val = $(this).val();
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
 $('span.'+val).show();
} else {$('span.'+val).hide();};
});

});
```

Comment: kylek...if the checkbox is checked and the <li> contains that category then I want the entire <li> to show and have the other <Li>'s that do not contain the item to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$inputs.on('change', function() {
    var allClasses = $inputs.map(function() {
       return this.value; 
    }).get();
    var $checkedInputs = $inputs.filter(function() {
        return this.checked === true;
    });
    var checkedClasses = $checkedInputs.map(function() {
          return this.value; 
    }).get();
    var $uncheckedInputs = $inputs.filter(function() {
          return this.checked === false; 
    });

    // Show All initially
    $('.' + allClasses.join(', .')).show();
    // If unchecked not equal to total length invoke condition 
    if($inputs.length !== $uncheckedInputs.length) {
        $('.' + allClasses.join(', .')).not($('.' + checkedClasses.join(', .'))).hide();
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/s5sAG/)**

Had to tweak couple of classes like `dry beans` , `brussels sprouts` and `chinese greens` with a `-` between them as they meant a single class.

Comment: Sushanth,This looks good and is working well, I probably did not explain well that if the user selects Dry beans, then I want all <li>'s that do not contain dry beans to hide, if you unclick Dry Beans then all <li>'s reappear...does this make sense

Comment: @sburns.. I think if you select dry beans only `li` with dry- beans class is shown right

Comment: Thats correct it only shows dry beans, but I was hoping that it would show the entire <li> with all of the categories and not hide the rest of the categories that has dry beans and hide any entire <li> that does not contain dry beans

Comment: But there sold be some relationship ship between different li for that to happen right. Otherwise how would the code know that those should not be hidden. For example if you check beets, it only sows beets because that li has that class which is the condition

Comment: If any other li in the ul does not have beets then hide those li's thats the big addon I am looking for....I want to hide any li that does not have that category and shows the li's that do